# How to convert output from a split phase inverter to single phase with only 1 hot?

Tags: inverter, single-phase, split-phase

Here in USA, we use split phase 240VAC 60Hz.  In Philippines, they use single phase 220VAC also 60Hz.  How do I make an inverter designed for 240VAC split phase output work properly over there in Philippines for their appliances expecting 220VAC single phase?  I believe they use one hot and one neutral but I am not sure.  Is there some special way to connect it and/or do I need some special adapter or wiring harness?  The outlets there look similar to the NEMA 5-15R used here in USA, except many of them (I think) are tipped sideways and have 3 receptacles instead of the typical 2 vertical ones in USA.  They use a combination of both 2 prong (type A) and 3 prong (type B) plugs (even in the same house).  Type C plugs are also used but I am not so concerned with those.

Also, a friend of mine who is good with technical stuff told me their stuff will run even better with 240VAC so I might not even have to worry about the 20 "extra" volts.  All the appliances might "like" it (run more efficiently).  Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: perhaps they have magnetic tapped voltage stabilizers that work with 60Hz as these are only popular in 50 Hz markets

Comment: I already have step up/step down combination voltage converters with built it AVR.  I have it set for 220V input and it can do simultaneous 110V and 220V output.  It also has both a voltmeter and ammeter built in.  I've tested it with a window air conditioner and it seemed to handle it well.  Even a 120V 1500 watt hair dryer worked well using it.

Answer (score 2):

Philippine power (in the American zones) is a worldwide one-off: it is simply North American style power, but with neutral omitted.   Safety ground is still there, but it's halfway between the hots.

Indeed, any Philippine appliance can come to the US, be plugged into a properly wired NEMA 6, and be happy as a clam.

In the Euro-power zones of the Philippines, it's the same except safety ground is pegged to one of the poles instead of halfway in between.  In other words, bog-standard 5-continent power.

So, to make your inverter work with the Philippines, where you would normally provide a standard NEMA 14 receptacle, *instead, provide NEMA 6* and don't serve neutral.

Although truth be told, even though the NEMA connector system provides the correct socket for this (NEMA 6), my understanding is that in practice, the Philippines prefer NEMA 5 even though it's wrong.  (what are they thinking?)

I wouldn't say things made for 220V "work even better" on 240V.  However, I would say that anything made 220/240 for the North American market, will be built for 240V.  Also, anything built for the Euro/5-continent market will at least be built for 230V as that is the Euro standard, and maybe even 240V since that is the British standard.

Comment: I like your additions. They are good but that's not the point. They also provide complementary experiences that add to and don't entirely overlap those of existing contributors. So it expands the contribution circle, so to speak. And that's a *nice-to-have*.